# How do I get the result or return value of a Task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Can someone explain to me how to return the result of a Task?
I currently am trying to do the following but my Tasks are not returning my List that I expect? What is the problem here?

```
static void Main()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    List<string> sha256_hashes = new List<string>();
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    sha256_hashes.Add("hash00");
    sha256_hashes.Add("hash01");
    sha256_hashes.Add("hash03");
    foreach(string sha256 in sha256_hashes)
    {
        string _sha256 = sha256;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAdditionalInfo(_sha256));
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
   //I want to put all the results of each task from tasks but the problem is
   //I can't use the Result method from the _task because Result method is not available
   //below is my plan to get all the results:
   foreach(var _task in tasks)
   {
        if(_task.Result.Count >= 1)  //got an error Only assignment, call, increment, dec....
             results.AddRange(_task.Result); //got an error Only assignment, call, increment, dec....
   }

   //Do some work about results
}
static List<string> GetAdditionalInfo(string hash)
{
    //this code returns information about the hash in List of strings

}
```

Comment: `Task.Result` isn't array.

Comment: `Task` doesn't have a `Result` property - it looks like `tasks` should have type `List<Task<List<string>>>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To return a result from a `Task` you need to define the `Task` as such: `Task<TResult>` and pass the return type of the result as a generic parameter. (Otherwise the Task will return nothing)

For Example:

```
        // Return a value type with a lambda expression
        Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 1);
        int i = task1.Result;

        // Return a named reference type with a multi-line statement lambda.
        Task<Test> task2 = Task<Test>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string s = ".NET";
            double d = 4.0;
            return new Test { Name = s, Number = d };
        });
        Test test = task2.Result;

        // Return an array produced by a PLINQ query
        Task<string[]> task3 = Task<string[]>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\";
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

            var result = (from file in files.AsParallel()
                          let info = new System.IO.FileInfo(file)
                          where info.Extension == ".jpg" 
                          select file).ToArray();

            return result;
        });
```

**The problem is that you are not specifying that the Task is going to return anything**.

You have defined a List of Tasks that do not return anything.

What you will need to do is specify the return type in the `Task` when you define `Task` as the generic type for the `List` in your case. Something like:

```
var taskLists = new List<Task<List<string>>>();
```

This is how you specify the return type for a `Task`

Comment: lol - straight from Microsoft's website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task